# Google Chrome extension to display url of current tab by click of button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would simply like to display the URL of the current tab that I am in by clicking a button from my chrome extension. I tried using alert() in popup.js but it is not working. I am new to javascript and chrome extensions so please have mercy :)

The popup.html code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Save URL</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2> FYDP: Save Current Tab URL </h2>
    <button id="Get URL"> Get the URL of this page! </button>
</body>

</html>
```

The popup.js code is:

```
    function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {

    var queryInfo = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    };

    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {

        var tab = tabs[0];

        var url = tab.url;
        document.getElementById("Get URL").onclick = alert(url);

        console.assert(typeof url == 'string', 'tab.url should be a string');

        callback(url);
    });
}
```

The manifest.json code is:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Save URL",
    "description": "This extension saves the URL of the current tab in a 
    variable ",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click here!"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can't display alerts from javascript events in chrome extension popups (see [this other stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165149/javascript-alerts-in-an-onclick-in-a-chrome-extension-popup-immediately-disappea) for more info). But in case you were curious what it *would* look like if you could, here's what it'd be (I changed a couple things in your code):

- ids can't have spaces in them, so I changed the button's id to `get-url`
- You have to register the event listener on the button, you were registering it in a function that was never called so the listener was never added
- I moved the script to the end of the `<body>` because you're using `querySelector`, and script tags are executed in-line, which means that only elements that are *before* the script tag are rendered yet. That is to say, you have to have the script tag after the button tag
- I added the `tabs` permission to the manifest-- you need it to query all tabs

popup.js:

```
function getCurrentTabUrl() {
  var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true,
  }

  chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0]
    alert(tab.url)
  })
}

document.querySelector('#get-url').addEventListener('click', getCurrentTabUrl)
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save URL</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2> FYDP: Save Current Tab URL </h2>
    <button id="get-url"> Get the URL of this page!</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Save URL",
  "description": "This extension saves the URL of the current tab in a variable",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Actually, [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission is sufficient, it's designed for this purpose.

Comment: Ah didn't know that, thak's @wOxxOm! I couldn't find any docs on it on the tabs page so I went with that just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jay ! Could you please explain why `var tab = tabs[0]` is needed? Why doesn't `tab.url` trigger the same thing?

Comment: There’s actually no need @shadynoob ! You could easily just do tabs[0].url

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. So tabs is the parameter passed in to that callback (aka function) from chrome.tabs.query, and it contains the URL there, so you have to at least access the tabs variable.